# How can I use localstorage to display the values on my web page using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm on a mission to make a simple webpage with an inputfield and a button on my HTML page. Using JavaScript I need to store the input in localstorage, which I got to work. However when I press the button I want the value that's being stored to display in a new div element created in JavaScript together with a remove button to remove the item from localstorage.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="" id="inp-value">
    <button id="btn">Klicka här!</button>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.onclick = function(){
    const value = inpValue.value;

    localStorage.setItem("Name", value);
    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these

**Storage.getItem()**

> ```
> const storedName = localStorage.getItem("Name");
> ```

**Storage.removeItem()**

> ```
> localStorage.removeItem("Name");
> ```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help me to display the value of localstorage on my webpage in a new div :/

Comment: `document.querySelector('#div_id_for_display').innerHTML = storedName;` will work

Comment: script.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')
    at HTMLButtonElement.btn.onclick got this error message

Comment: Do you have  a div for display? if no, add `<div id="div_id_for_display"></div>` to your html

Comment: This assignment dont allow me to make a div inside the html, supposedto do that in JavaScript when the button is clicked

Comment: The **assignment**! duh.. Use `document.body.appendChild(\`<div id="name_display">${storedName}</div>\`)`. No more assignment questions please

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution.

Javascript code

```
 <script>
       
        btnClick = function () {
            var inputValue = document.getElementById("inp-value").value;
            var ul = document.getElementById("list");
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            var listItems = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

            localStorage.setItem(`item-${listItems.length + 1}`, inputValue);

            var html = `<li  id="item-${listItems.length + 1}"><div><lable>${inputValue}</lable> <button onclick="removeClick(${listItems.length + 1})" >X</button></div> </li>`
            ul.innerHTML += html;

        };
        removeClick = function (item_id) {
          
            var ul = document.getElementById("list");
            localStorage.removeItem(`item-${item_id}`);
            ul.removeChild(ul.childNodes[item_id]);
        }
    </script>
```

Html

```
<body>
    <input type="text" name="" id="inp-value">
    <button id="btn" onclick="btnClick()">Klicka här!</button>

    <ul id="list">

    </ul>
</body>
```